# How to load a GeoJSON (in a javascript variable ... ) in MapBox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I need to load in MapBox GL JS a layer based on a GeoJSON and I started form this example

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

I've my data in a Javascript variable

```
   var theRouteJsonText = "{ \"type\": \"geojson\", \"data\": { \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\": {}, \"geometry\":";
   theRouteJsonText = theRouteJsonText + JSON.stringify(theCoords);
   theRouteJsonText = theRouteJsonText + "} }";
```

....  and its value is, for example, ...

```
{
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [9.123777, 39.213546],
                [9.124838, 39.214753],
                [9.125036, 39.219553],
                [9.123548, 39.220278],
                [9.122217, 39.219429],
                [9.121313, 39.219682],
                [9.120233, 39.221339],
                [9.119572, 39.221669],
                [9.118786, 39.221757],
                [9.118277, 39.223214],
                [9.118174, 39.223181],
                [9.116678, 39.225676],
                [9.116099, 39.226343],
                [9.111633, 39.228077],
                [9.11111, 39.228516],
                [9.110992, 39.229156],
                [9.111139, 39.231757]
            ],
            "type": "LineString"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add the GeoJSON layer to the map in this manner ....

```
map.addSource("route", theRouteJsonText);

map.addLayer({
    "id": "route",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "route",
    "layout": {
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
    },
    "paint": {
        "line-color": "#888",
        "line-width": 8
    }
});
```

When execute my Chrome console says

[image]

Suggestions / examples / alternatives?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved, here you are the solutions ...

This is the MapBox GL JS sample code ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.23.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.23.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2VzYXJlIiwiYSI6Im1LdmxtRU0ifQ.uoGK9BB9eywCPknCRlB9JA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource("route", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                    [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                    [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                    [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                    [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                    [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                    [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                    [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                    [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                    [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                    [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                    [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                    [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                    [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                    [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                    [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                    [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                    [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                    [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                    [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                    [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "route",
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

... and this is the revised code using the GeoJSON in a Javascript variable ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.23.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.23.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2VzYXJlIiwiYSI6Im1LdmxtRU0ifQ.uoGK9BB9eywCPknCRlB9JA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

theCoords = {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
    ]
};

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource("route", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": theCoords
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "route",
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried something like this

```
  map.addSource("route", {
     "type": "geojson",
     "data": {
       "type": "FeatureCollection",
       "features": theRouteJsonText
     }
   });
```